# How to configure EC2 Security Group Firewall?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have security group on AWS EC2.

The security group is configured to Allow all connections from my IP Adress.

This works fine from the office.

[image]

When I'm connected through a mobile phone wifi spot, I change the security group to add a new inbound rule with my new ip adress the same way I do for the office (**Allow All traffic from my new IP**).

This doesn't work. I'm unable to connect.

And if I add the (dangerous) rule : **Allow All traffic from Anywhere**, it works.

Does anyone know the reason to that please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Obviously because you whitelisted the wrong IP.

Comment: @luk2302 : Actually I'm selecting the "My Ip" in the select list suggested by AWS, and AWS types automatically the IP Adress. I'm not typing it manually. When I check on whatismyipaddress, It's also the same that is shown. Can AWS chooses a wrong IP ?

Comment: just to be clear,  you got the ip of the phone and not your computer right?

Comment: @dannykaplunski On AWS, there is a select list to choose from. I'm selecting "My IP" then AWS selects automatically an IP Address. So I assume that this is the IP Address that AWS sees I'm connecting from. In this case it's the IP of the computer. Because when I checks WhatIsMyAddress, I'm getting exacly the same value.

Comment: If you perform a WhatIsMyAddress check on both your phone and your computer - do the 2 addresses match? Also, mobile internet tends to change IP a lot more than a hardwired internet connections - are you sure the IP is still correct when your testing?

Comment: @MisterSmith when I check WhatIsMyAddress I'm getting different Ip's from the computer and the phone. And yes when testing, I'm still having the same IP value.

Comment: Do you have a VPN/Proxy or something causing your PC to appear on a different IP?  I assume if you add both IP's it works as expected?

Comment: On some networks, web traffic goes through a different proxy due to security/caching. As a result, your IP address via a web browser might appear different to your IP address when using SSH. If your goal is to connect via SSH, then temporarily open to all IP addresses, connect to the instance via SSH, then disconnect. Then, connect again. The login messages will include the IP address that was previously used to access the instance. You can put that IP address in the Security Group and it will work for future SSH connections from your computer.